# Matching Altium and manufacturing DRC technology

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I want to input inside my Altium designer the DRC of a manufacturer shown in the link below. There are some importance settings I need to find but the terminology differs from Altium to designers laws on its website.

I will sent a question to the manufacturer but I can't see what is the clearance definition for the manufacturer?

There is a tool of a manufacturer shown in the link below.

If I understand correctly 6/6 means 6 mil width 6 mil space between traces. Finished copper of 1 oz means that the thickness of the substrate is 0.035 mm. I chose some options as shown below. What happens when I press calculate? How can I get the clearance DRC from it?

https://www.pcbway.com/orderonline.aspx

https://www.pcbway.com/capabilities.html

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Calculate on the PCBway page will calculate the new price after you've changed the parameters. Tighter design rules mean higher cost.

On the PCB rules dialog if you edit the minimum clearance field (shown as N/A in my image), **all** the numbers in the table will be changed to that one number. If any are not appropriate you can then go and change them (I prefer a larger than minimum clearance to poly for manufacturability and to avoid too many stupid slivers of copper). 6 mils (0.006") is 0.1524mm

Don't forget to hit apply afterward.

[image]

You'll also have to set the minimum trace width.

[Here](https://github.com/Fermium/Open-Altium-Rules) is a github set of rules that someone has developed for 8/8 0.3mm minimum hole size. There end up being 40 or 50 in the .RUL file.

Comment: Hello Spehro , where to look for these space and size parameters in the capabilities link bellow?

https://www.pcbway.com/capabilities.html

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Spehro, Is there other rule files for thicker 0.5mm traces?
is 8/8 is a standart for this FAB? Thanks.

Comment: It's right in the selection. You can pick 3, 4, 5, 6 or 8 mil. 8 mil will be the cheapest. Of course you don't have to use traces that small. 0.254 mm (10 mils) minimum is narrow enough for a lot of work, and you can make your traces just as wide as you like as far as PCBway is concerned. I don't see much reason for a maximum trace width rule but I believe there's such a design rule in Altium. If so you can just set it to something large like 10mm or 20mm.